# How do I change the font color in choicebox?

Tags: javafx, fonts, colors, combobox

I tried to change my font-color in the choicebox , but all the anwer I found is change the label inside . I don't know how do I change font-color with this...

This is my fxml with choicebox↓

```html
<ChoiceBox fx:id="capacity_box1" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="113.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="193.0" styleClass="choiceBox">
     <items>
           <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                   <fx:reference source="list.millilitre" />
                    <fx:reference source="list.cubiccentermeter" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.litre" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.cubicmeter" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.Teaspoon" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.Tablespoon" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.gallon" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.cubicinch" />
                  <fx:reference source="list.cubicfoot" />
             </FXCollections>
       </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Comment: If you want to change color for individual item, I don't think that is possible. If you want to apply a uniform font color for the whole choicebox, then this should be possible with a stylesheet `.choice-box>.label, { -fx-text-fill: MYCOLOR; }`

Comment: `ChoiceBox` has an implicit label inside for every item, don't worry about it.

Comment: Oh , it works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Hi I do believe that I'm providing a better solution

in your CSS file create the following

```
.choice-box .menu-item .label { 
-fx-text-fill: WHITE; 
}
```